# neo4j, neo4jclient order by Turkish (or other) alphabetical order

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

is there a way to order nodes according to a property's Turkish alphabetical order?

Currently non-ASCII characters are ordered after "Z"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neo4j uses Java's string ordering,

so if you can configure Neo4j in `conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf` to use your locale, then it should work.

Comment: so i tried wrapper.lang=tr_TR, wrapper.lang=tr-TR, wrapper.java.additional=-Duser.language=tr,
wrapper.java.additional=-Duser.country=TR
so far and none of those were able to fix it. What am i missing? Thanks in advance..